# In area chart how to use gradient colour

Tags: highcharts

How can I add gradient color in an area chart. Please help. I need the gradient in the pink colored area of the graph.

Following is my code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
          type: 'area',
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Dummy Data',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            color: 'pink'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Please take look at the example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/HkeXp/

```
fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#ff0000'],
                        [1, '#f4f4f4']
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: But this is not the thing I require...How can I implement my requirement by my given example. What I need to change ??

Comment: But what is wrong with my example? Only what you need is change color.

Comment: I unable to change the color. Following is my code. Please let me know what I need to change to get the result. I have added the following   plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 1, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    }

Comment: Can I make series: name option non click-able to the user ?

Comment: @SayakBandyopadhyay in the legend?